# How to get the exit code for "os.popen(command)"?

Tags: python, python-os

I am using a shell script to run the commands.

When running the command using this

```
os.popen(command).readline()
```

I want to get the exit code of that command.

Please let me know how we get the exit code in this case.

Comment: Use the `subprocess` module instead of `os.popen()`.

Comment: But i want to use oc.popen() module only

Comment: @ShanthiK :  `os.popen(command)` is not valid bash code. Do you ask about Python? If so, tag your question with _python_.

Comment: *Why* do you want to use an obsolescent function which doesn't do what you want instead of a modern one which does?

Answer (score 4):

When you call `close()` on the file object returned by `os.popen()`, it returns the termination status if it's not `0`. You use [`os.waitstatus_to_exitcode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.waitstatus_to_exitcode) to extract the exit code from this.

```
f = os.popen(command)
line = f.readline()
status = f.close()
if status:
    print(os.waitstatus_to_exitcode(status))
```